# Is the repetition of "faster than you can say Jack Robinson" deliberate in C.S. Lewis' books?

Tags: the-chronicles-of-narnia, cs-lewis

In C. S. Lewis's Chronicles of Narnia, I noticed the repetition of the phrase "faster than you could say Jack Robinson" as a descriptive sentence in both The Lion, The Witch, And The Wardrobe and The Magician's Nephew. Was this a phrase of the time, a saying coined by Lewis, or a deliberate reference to an in-universe person?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

"Faster than you can say Jack Robinson" (meaning very quickly) is a common English expression, from well before C. S. Lewis's time to the present day. The online [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/) (paywalled but you may have access through your public or university library) has citations ranging from 1763 to 2016. Quoting from the Wikipedia page for [Jack Robinson (mythical person)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Robinson_(mythical_person)):

> **Jack Robinson** is a name present in two common figures of speech. When referring to Jack Robinson, it is used to represent quickness. In contrast, the phrase "(A)round Jack Robinson's barn" has the opposite connotation, implying slowness, as it is often used to refer to circumlocution, circumvention, or doing things in roundabout or unnecessarily complicated ways.
>
> [. . . .]
>
> Multiple citations explain references to Jack Robinson as meaning quickness of thought or deed. The normal usage is, "(something is done) **faster than you can say Jack Robinson**", or otherwise, "**before you can say Jack Robinson**". The phrase can be traced back to the eighteenth century.

Comment: Good answer, but I'm not sure I'd consider it common in the present. I would consider it old fashioned in my native British English, and I don't recall hearing it in any of the mass of US media we consume so I presume it's now uncommon there too.

Comment: @JackAidley Forsooth 'tis less common now than 'twas threescore years ago.

Comment: Is this the same Jack who was nimble, quick, and jumped over candlesticks?

Comment: Here's an [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you+can+say+Jack+Robinson&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyou%20can%20say%20Jack%20Robinson%3B%2Cc0) of the phrase "you can say Jack Robinson", which is found in both of the samples bolded in this Answer. Seems to have been rising since a low point in 1976. NGrams are limited to five words, so I can't do one for the complete phrases.

Comment: For what it's worth, C.S. Lewis called himself "Jack" and his friends and family used that name as well.  Whether it influenced this word choice is hard to say.

Comment: "Jack Robinson" is also a stereotypical English name, and the Narnia books are quite keen on stereotypical English things. However, that's a very post-hoc rationale; consider that if Lewis had said "in two shakes of a lamb's tail," we'd probably be reading Christian symbolism into _that_. Sometimes a Jack Robinson is just a Jack Robinson.

Comment: To an American, there’s a famous athlete from that time period named Jackie Robinson, but the expression is much older than he.

Comment: @Davislor As a kid I knew of Jackie Robinson and loved the Narnia books. I did not make a connection between the two. The phrase "faster than you could say $whatever" has strong implications of being "very fast." You didn't need to know what "Jack Robinson" meant, only that you couldn't finish saying it before something else was done first.

Comment: I would say that it is not yet archaic even in American English.  I am not elderly (yet) and would easily and readily recognize the phrase.  I would think of it as something that would turn up in movies or television programs from the 30's to the 60's - making it familiar to boomers and Generation X, but maybe a little obscure to people younger than that.